# Using Raspberry Pi to develop applications in .NET

Tags: .net, raspberry-pi

While i was browsing the net I saw a post about this raspberry pi, I googled it and upon reading what a Raspberry pi is a million ideas popped on my head. I'm thinking to use Rpi for a business, Im a Programmer and a little extra income would be great. So im thinking of creating applications and selling them bundled with the hardware. That's where the Rpi comes in. So can I develop .NET applications on Rpi? or should i learn a specific language for this?

Comment: As I understand, .NET only is for windows operating systems. So i think you will need to learn a new language

Comment: You should try this question on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is too broad. You should try it on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs any language that can compile for the armv6 processor its based on. I would think you will want to keep it slim. It seems intended for python running on Linux but they are encouraging you to try anything/everything. Since it wont run windows it wont run .net - however you could look at c# with erm... mono. Then again there are very restrictive memory considerations since your options are limited to 256M and 512M versions. Think Android.

[Heres](http://elinux.org/CSharp_on_RPi) some info on c# / mono / RPi

Comment: Hmmm. So would it be alot easier if I code my application in Andriod?

Comment: I think that would be the sweet-spot for a profit based venture on the RPi, yea. You could consider adding a small touch-screen even. Altho the cost of a touch screen doesn't jive with the price of the device. oo - figure out how to make it work with an existing/old smart-phone and you could maybe have some fun :)

Comment: That's exactly what i have in mind! :) to add a touch screen and make it look like a All-In_one PC.